# Gulp plugin/task to load assets asynchronously

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, gulp

I have a gulp task configured that takes all assets (css/js files)
minifies them and outputs with the revision postfix:

```
gulp.task('build', ['make-cache'], function() {
var assets = $.useref.assets({searchPath: './'}),
    js = plugins.filter('**/scripts.js');

    return gulp
    .src(config.index)
    // handle errors
    .pipe(plugins.plumber())
    // collect all assets from source file by the means of useref
    .pipe(assets)
    // process js
    .pipe(js)
    .pipe($.uglify())
    .pipe(js.restore())  
    // Take inventory of the file names for future rev numbers
    .pipe($.rev())
    // Apply the concat and file replacement with useref
    .pipe(assets.restore())
    .pipe($.useref())
    // Replace the file names in the html with rev numbers
    .pipe($.revReplace())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dist));
})
```

Note: in this example I use `gulp-load-plugins` plugin so the `$` is actually a variable that has all gulp plugins loaded.

This creates files as follows `scripts-abcd123.js` and changes the revision in the html file.

I wonder if there is a gulp plugin that can take this generated javascript file and add an asynchronous loader of the html file.

So, instead of:
    `<script src="scripts-abcd123.js"></script>`

it becomes:

```
var sc=document.createElement("script");
sc.src="scripts-abcd123.js";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(sc);
```

The similar technique is used on smashing magazine site (e.g. for loading stylesheets):

```
<script id="smash-main-css-js">var ms=document.createElement("link");ms.rel="stylesheet";ms.href="http://www.smashingmagazine.com/wp-content/themes/smashing-magazine/assets/css/main.min.css?ver=3.2";document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(ms);</script>
```

It is definitely not a manual alteration. As far as I know, they use grunt for it. I'm searching for the similar solution for gulp. Or, at least point my attention to a grunt plugin, if there is a public one.
I tried to search in google but all results are related to gulp-load-plugins which just loads gulp plugins automatically and which I use.